# Failing to see where my projections and assumptions are wrong with OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, gis

I have made a prototype in matlab that projects some Aerial photo to the ground and visualized it with plots in matlab and everything is as expected.

Then migrating to web something goes wrong with my projections.

Example:
Each image is annotated with lat,lng and also wsg 84 utm 32 easting and nothing.

When I in matlab compare the distance of two images i get a distance of 159 meters.

```
>> norm([696975.558, 6191855.032]-[696952.619, 6191697.477],2)
ans =   159.2161
```

but when doing it on the projected lat,lng the distance is almost twice as much.

```
var coord = openLayers.proj.transform([i.longitude(), i.latitude()], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
```

above is how i get from the image lng and lat to the EPSG:3857.

```
>> norm([1352002.183944147, 7525040.504347302]-[1351948.7706260746 7524762.187661538],2)
ans =  283.3958
```

We have a function that given a image position calculates the 4 corners projected to the ground in relative offset given in meters, and trying to visualize the overlap of the images. But when the footprint is given in meters and the projected coordinates are almost twice the size this ofcause dont illustrate the overlap correctly.

Question is, are there any way to get from the utm 32 position to EPSG:3857 or will I have to first take the relative footprint in UTM, convert the points to lat lng and then use openlayers transform again?

Comment: Is you question to do with the display of the image or the measurement. In general, EPSG:3857 is designed for ease of mathematical calculation when generating tiles for "slippy map" interfaces that cover the whole globe. A downside of this is that it suffers from chronic scale distortion, and is not good for accurately measuring distance -- a distortion that increases as you move aware from the pole. The is a general property of Mercator projections -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection -- they are conformal, but at the cost of scale.

Comment: I figured out how to use proj4js to do a transformation of my UTM 32 Points to EPSG:3857 and it looks as expected.